# ASP.NET MVC Linq Join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on ASP.NET Core MVC project with scaffoleded views and controllers from models.
**Context:**
I got three models:

1. User

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection(Contact) contacts { get; set; }
```

2. Contact

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ContactTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public string ContactValue { get; set; }

    public virtual User user { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactType type { get; set; }
```

3. ContactType

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string TypeName { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection(Contact) contacts { get; set; }

In /Users/Details/{id} controller User's details are fetched from context and passed to View:

```
    public async Task Details(int? id)
    {
        var user = await _context.User
                    .Include(k => k.Contact)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        return View(user);
    }
```

In /Users/Details.cshtml view, I am trying to write out **{ContactType.TypeName} : {Contact.ContactValue}** but not successfully. I am trying this:

```
    @foreach (var contact in Model.contacts)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(contactItem => contact.ContactType.TypeName)                    
        @Html.DisplayFor(contactItem => contact.ContactValue)
    }
```

and getting [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHi8g.png) (contact.ContactType.TypeNames are empty). If I try:

```
    @foreach (var contact in Model.contacts)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(contactItem => contact.ContactTypeId)                    
        @Html.DisplayFor(contactItem => contact.ContactValue)
    }
```

and I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJwCK.png) (Ids are writed out). But ContactTypeIds are not what I want to writeout.
**Issue:** How to writeout **ContactType.TypeName** for every Contact?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to include the `ContactType` as well in that case like below. Moreover, your return type is wrong, it should be `Task<ActionResult>` instead of simply returning a `Task`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    var user = await _context.User
                .Include(k => k.Contact)
                .Include(k => k.Contact.Select(c => c.ContactType))
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. With `Include(k => k.Contact.Select(c => c.ContactType))`, exception is thrown: `InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'k => {from Contact c in [k].Contact select [c].ContactType}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.`. Should I try with some Join?

Comment: `Include(k => k.Contact.Join(_context.ContactType, cont => cont.ContactTypeId, ctype => ctype.Id, (cont, ctype) => new { TypeName = ctype.TypeName}))`, it also throws exception: `InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'k => {from Contact cont in [k].Contact join ContactType ctype in value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1[door2door.Models.ContactType]) on [cont].ContactTypeId equals Convert([ctype].Id) select new <>f__AnonymousType01(TypeName = [ctype].TypeName)}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.`